# How to create a cookie, increment its value and make it accessible it on other pages using jquery

Tags: jquery, cookies

How to create a cookie and assign it a value and therefore increment its value over a click event, display it on the current page and also that cookie value should be displayed on another pages as well. I am new to jquery plz help me.

Comment: This link should explain how to do it with a plugin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery

Comment: not helpful plz something else

Answer (score 0):

So JQuery does not have this functionality built in. You will have to download a plugin. As I am not experienced in how to set cookies in JQuery (I use PHP to do this), I apologize as I can only send you resources that may help. Here's another site I found that may help you set up the plugin and get stared with setting cookies and recalling them through JQuery. You may want to start out with basics, though, as this requires some prerequisite knowledge.

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/